# Using date stored as custom field to filter posts displayed in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, date-time

This seems like a fairly common problem, but I'm posting this as I've yet to find a solution to my problem here on WP Answers - any help is HUGELY appreciated!

Ok - so I have a custom post type of 'events' where I capture the date of the event using a custom field and store it as a unix timestamp. Filtering posts on the front end is not a problem using the following code to show future events only:

```
$events = new WP_Query( 'post_type=events&posts_per_page=-1&meta_key=date_value&orderby=meta_value&meta_compare=>=&meta_value='.time().'&order=ASC' );
```

I've tried to filter the results in the admin in the same way using a `pre_get_posts` filter:

```
function events_pre_get_posts($query) {
  if (is_admin()) {
    if (isset($query->query_vars['post_type'])) {
      if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events') {
          $query->set('meta_key', 'date_value');
          $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
          $query->set('meta_compare', '>=');
          $query->set('meta_value', time());
          $query->set('order', 'ASC');
      }
    }
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts' , 'events_pre_get_posts');
```

But in the admin this code just makes all my posts disappear!

I'm also trying to find a way to show past events in the back end and I'm really stuck there too! I not sure the best way to do this - perhaps a toggle on the 'events' posts page to view past / future events.

Help!!

Answer (score 2):

Second try: ;-)

`pre_get_posts` runs AFTER `parse_query()`. `parse_query()` transforms 'meta_key' etc. into 'meta_query'. `get_posts()` doesn't seem to react on 'meta_key' etc. directly. So try adding `$query->parse_query()` after your `$query->set()` calls or use filter that runs before `parse_query` (edited, the `parse_query()` filter doesn't work, either - it runs too late).

Edit: to do the switch:

```
function my_timeswitch() {
    $operators = array(
        '>=' => 'future',
        '<=' => 'past'
    );
    ?>
    <select name='meta_compare'>
        <?php
            foreach ($operators as $k => $v) {
                printf( "<option %s value='%s'>%s</option>\n", selected($_GET['meta_compare'], $k, false), esc_attr($k), __($v));
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'my_timeswitch');
```

This may work just on it's own. If not, you'll have to change the name to something else, then register a new public query variable via the `query_vars` filter and then react on it via the `parse_query` filter.

Comment: Why not just add that to the original answer?

Comment: Hang on - it does work! I add $query->parse_query() after all the other query stuff and it now only displays event that have yet to occur! Wicked - thanks so much @wyrfel! --- BTW, any idea if it's possible to toggle the query on the admin side between past and upcoming events?!

Comment: @t31os I wasn't sure how to best go about it. What's wrong with two answers if they are truely distinct answers? Basically, i decided for a second rather than editing, because it was a very distinct answer and it left the 'comment-story' on the first one intact.

Comment: @Richard Sweeney: Sure you can build a switch that applies a different filter. All depends on how and when you're adding the filter. You can also do both at the same time, i think, if you depend on the new 'meta_query' query value of 3.1, as that allows several meta queries at once, if i get it right.

Comment: @wyrfel I find stack exchange confusing - I'm sure there must be a better way to present different answers or edits and these comments (rather than 'answers') kinda suck! I keep hitting enter by force of pure habit!

Might you have time and/or energy to point me in the right direction regarding how to go about constructing a switch statement to toggle views? I'm rather a php/WordPress noob I'm afraid to say! Cheers

Comment: @Richard Sweeney: see edit

Comment: @wyfel - thanks for this - it doesn't work 'out of the box'. Unfortunately my PHP and/or WordPress skills really aren't up to scratch to play around with this to make it work. Thanks for all your help anyway, it's much appreciated!

Comment: @Richard Sweeney Does it at least bring up the dropdown? (Probably in too many places? ;-) )

Comment: @wyrfel yes it does. When I try and filter the results I get the following URL: `edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=concerts&action=-1&m=0&meta_compare=%3C%3D&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1`

Comment: @Richard Sweeney: That looks good. Sorry, forgot to mention that you need to remove your `$query->set('meta_compare', '>=');` line.

Comment: @wurfel, shucks... No joy. Removed the code you suggested - also tried lots of variations on bits of code to remove and even removing the entire function. No luck!

Comment: @Richard Sweeney: Argh, then you'll need to use a totally custom query var and add a parse_query filter...sorry, too much for me right now.

Comment: @wyrfel - no worries, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `current_time('mysql')` instead of `time()`.

`time()` returns a unix timestamp (that is an integer), `current_time('mysql')` returns a mysql timestamp.

Comment: Cheers @wyrfel, the value is in fact stored as a unix timestamp, so time() works ok actually.

Comment: @Richard Sweeney: I see, was jumping to conclusions...see second answer.